# Actionscript Object vs Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, actionscript

I am excellent in Javascript, but currently started learning ActionScript. Can anyone teach me the difference between JavaScript Object and ActionScript Object ?

I request answer in few lines of description. Explanation with examples would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, but google for the difference between prototypical languages (js and as2) vs class based languages (as3) for a summary

Comment: @32bitkid, I knew both of them similar, but may be few differences between them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, Actionscript is a conventional Object Oriented Language in which it has Classes defining the structure of the objects instantiated.

JavaScript is a completely different flavour; you don't have access to Classes; you can emulate them (and that's a common trend for someone who's coming from a more conventional OOP mindset), but its strength comes exactly from the freedom you have. In a nutshell:

Objects are Functions - Functions are Objects
Objects are created in runtime, and can serve as a base (prototype), for creating other objects which, in its own advantage, can be morphed and override with new properties and methods, without having a strong bound to the strict definition of a class.

Comment: 1+ Yes Andre. You are correct. I found the class documentation of Actionscript obejct here.                                 http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html

Answer (score 5):

ActionScript has two different models in fact.

1. You can create classical ECMA-script objects either using literals or using the `new`-operator in conjunction with `Function` objects. Such objects work according to ECMA-standard.
2. You can create objects by instantiating ActionScript classes much like you would in Java for example. These objects ensure runtime type safety, i.e. if you try to assign a `Foo` value to a field typed as `Bar` you will get a runtime exception (or even a compile time exception if the object's type is known at compile time).

It should be noted, that you can compile AS3 with ECMA-script compatibility mode. In that case, AFAIK *all* objects will act as ECMA-script objects, sacrificing both execution speed and runtime type safety, but giving you flexibility.

Comment: 1+ you seems to be flash master